# Email received from Salesforce has weird 'Via' string

Tags: email, apex-email-service, mass-email

When I send an Email from SF to someone as myself(John Doe(john@johndoe.com), user receiving the email has some weird 'Via' string displayed along with my name when viewd in Gmail.

Eg. John Doe via ksxvvovir8o4350h.ma6hdoyapghvy7of.r4mia6o.9-payleaq.ap4.bnc.salesforce.com

What is this string and is there a way I can remove it or make it look pretty?!

Thanks!

Comment: Set up email relaying, otherwise this is expected behaviour and helps to prevent the email being classed as spam. To send it without the via would in effect be spoofing.

Comment: Or actually you could try setting up an organisation wide email address, I can't remember if they also add the via email.

Comment: Thanks Girbot! I like the idea of Email relaying. Before I turn it on I would like to know if there is any drawback to it?

Comment: From personal experience the email administrators weren't happy with it, so that may be hardest bridge to cross,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Girbot for your help.

Email relaying is the solution to get rid of that string.

More details here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005793&language=en_US

And if you are using Gapps for business, check this article: http://www.grooveapp.com/blog/salesforce-remove-via-gmail/

Comment: Grooveapp link above is broken.  Try this link: https://blog.groove.co/blog/google-apps-as-email-relay-for-salesforce-to-remove-via-disclaimer